# Populating a ListView using data input from an EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to populate a list view using data taken from an edit text. The process is taking the data from the edit text and putting them in an ArrayList then using an ArrayAdapter using this ArrayList to populate the list view. What I've done so far is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    return true;
                if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) {
                    list.add(et.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println(list);
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.main_layout ,list);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This returns

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource
>   ID to be a TextView"

I tried adding an **empty TextView** to my XML. When I run the code, the new textview is added with an edittext to the list view, but only one time. So 2 errors occurring here. The edittext being added and only works once.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,**R.layout.main_layout** ,list);

**main_layout layout should be textview layout like below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"/>
```

or **you can use androids simple textview** like below.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,list);
```

Comment: Totally forgot I could use the android's views. Thanks for the answer, marked it as correct!